# Is there a way to submit course work submission when there is no submission id using Google API

Tags: python, google-classroom

Is there a way to submit course work submission when there is no submission id using Google APIs . The API reference Method: courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.turnIn requires the "id" field (Identifier of the student submission) but I do not have it since I'm trying to turnin for the first time

Tried to loop through the coursework using method Method: courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list which requires courseId and courseWorkId but I could find the "id" of a submission

Comment: Have you tried using the `id` from the response using the `courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list ` to the `id` parameter required in `ourses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.turnIn`?